# Why I can not find zipfile library in PyCharm (2019 3.3)

Tags: python, zip, python-zipfile

I am using PyCharm 2019 3.3.
Python version: 3.7

in my `pip install` I am getting an error as below

**Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement zipfile (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for zipfile**

Also I have tried with installing through project interpreter, still `zipfile` is not enlisted there.

Please let me know what is issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to install it, [zipfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html) is a [standard python library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/) for both Python 2.7 & Python 3.

Try `import zipfile`, that should work